# How to answer this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find how to evaluate:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k }2^k
$$

and also to describe a problem whose answer is the result/value.

How to proceed? I can see that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k }2^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{k} {n \choose k}{k \choose l}$$

but not sure how I can explore it further to find its value? Also what counting problem has this answer?

Comment: Hint: this expression should remind you of the binomial formula.

Comment: @Mark Ok right it's $3^n$ :) Thanks a lot! What should be a good counting problem whose answer is this though?

Comment: If you want a counting problem, try to compute the number of functions $\{1,2,...,n\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ in two different ways.

Comment: @Mark Thanks again!